# Flume-ng: source path and type for copying log file from local to HDFS

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, flume, flume-ng, bigdata

I am trying to copy some log files from `local` to `HDFS` using `flume-ng`. The `source` is `/home/cloudera/flume/weblogs/` and the `sink` is `hdfs://localhost:8020/flume/dump/`. A cron job will copy the logs from tomcat server to `/home/cloudera/flume/weblogs/` and I want to log files to be copied to `HDFS` as the files are available in `/home/cloudera/flume/weblogs/` using `flume-ng`. Below is the conf file I created:

```
agent1.sources= local
agent1.channels= MemChannel
agent1.sinks=HDFS

agent1.sources.local.type = ???
agent1.sources.local.channels=MemChannel

agent1.sinks.HDFS.channel=MemChannel
agent1.sinks.HDFS.type=hdfs
agent1.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.path=hdfs://localhost:8020/flume/dump/
agent1.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.fileType=DataStream
agent1.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.writeformat=Text
agent1.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.batchSize=1000
agent1.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.rollSize=0
agent1.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.rollCount=10000
agent1.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.rollInterval=600
agent1.channels.MemChannel.type=memory
agent1.channels.MemChannel.capacity=10000
agent1.channels.MemChannel.transactionCapacity=100
```

I am not able to understand:

1) what will be the value of `agent1.sources.local.type = ???`
2) where to mention the `source` path `/home/cloudera/flume/weblogs/` in the above conf file ?
3) Is there anything I am missing in the above conf file?

Please let me know on these.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use either  :

**An [Exec Source](https://flume.apache.org/FlumeUserGuide.html#exec-source)** and use a command (i.e. cat or tail on gnu/linux on you files)

**Or a [Spooling Directory Source](https://flume.apache.org/FlumeUserGuide.html#spooling-directory-source)** for read all files in a directory